# android vector drawable animation is not working

Tags: android, animation, vector

As mentioned in question I'm trying to do vector drawable animation for phone icon.
My requirement is to show phone animation like phone icon is moving that's it I try all suggestions from different sites,still animation is not working I am trying this from past two days still it is not happening.

Following files are my code if there is any problem please suggest me.

```
<vector
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:width="24dp"
android:height="24dp"
android:viewportWidth="24"
android:viewportHeight="24">
<path
    android:name="phone2"
    android:pathData="M 6.62 10.79 L 6.62 10.79 C 7.353 10.057 8.087 9.323 8.82 8.59 C 9.1 8.31 9.18 7.92 9.07 7.57 C 8.7 6.45 8.5 5.25 8.5 4 C 8.5 3.725 8.387 3.475 8.206 3.294 C 8.025 3.112 7.775 3 7.5 3 C 6.333 3 5.167 3 4 3 C 3.45 3 3 3.45 3 4 C 3 6.348 3.476 8.584 4.336 10.618 C 5.196 12.652 6.441 14.483 7.979 16.021 C 9.517 17.559 11.348 18.804 13.382 19.664 C 15.416 20.524 17.652 21 20 21 C 20.55 21 21 20.55 21 20 C 21 18.837 21 17.673 21 16.51 C 21 15.96 20.55 15.51 20 15.51 C 18.76 15.51 17.55 15.31 16.43 14.94 C 16.08 14.82 15.68 14.91 15.41 15.18 C 14.677 15.913 13.943 16.647 13.21 17.38 C 12.267 16.897 11.38 16.318 10.564 15.656 C 9.747 14.994 9.001 14.249 8.34 13.434 C 7.678 12.619 7.1 11.733 6.62 10.79"
    android:fillColor="#000"
    android:strokeWidth="1"/>
```

it is my Icon phone vector file.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animated-vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:drawable="@drawable/phone2_icon"
    tools:targetApi="lollipop">
<target
    android:animation="@animator/animation_rotation"
    android:name="animation"/>
</animated-vector>
```

This is animated vector file.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <objectAnimator
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:duration="6000"
        android:propertyName="rotation"
        android:valueFrom="0"
        android:valueTo="180"
        android:valueType="floatType"/>
</set>
```

This is my animation file which is placed in anim folder.

If any one know anything plz help out iam first time working with vector drawables.

[image]

Above image is phone icon i want it is just rotate from 180 to back normal.Like it will show moving animation.

Answer (score 1):

In the AnimatedVectorDrawable file you have to give "phone2" for android:name= under "target". Also against 'android:drawable="..." '   please give file name. If the name of your VectorDrawable file in "drawable" folder is "my_vector" and name of the animator file in "animator" folder is "animation_rotation" then your AnimatedVectorDrawable file should be as follows:

```
<animated-vector 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:drawable="@drawable/my_vector"
    tools:targetApi="lollipop">

    <target
        android:animation="@animator/animation_rotation"
        android:name="phone2"/>
</animated-vector>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer i will try this one.When i get this problem i left this one used GIF. To show that animation .Still i will try this if it will help i will accept it as answer.